# Getting error "loading openam suffix "

Tags: openam, opendj

Getting this error (error loading openam suffix 1) while creating default configuration in OpenAM 12.0.0 in ubuntu and tomcat 7.0.5. 

This error occurs at the OpenDJ setup step.

I'm following the exact same steps as given in getting started guide https://backstage.forgerock.com/#!/docs/openam/12.0.0/getting-started)

Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think adding the host name (the one which shows up as a result of hostname command on terminal) to /etc/hosts file resolved the issue.

Followed the following link-
https://bugster.forgerock.org/jira/browse/OPENAM-3876